# Wiring two motion sensors from separate locations to control a bank of lights in between both?

Tags: electrical

I want to turn on a bank of lights running along a deck between two entryways. The power switch is inside one doorway and feeds the circuit to the outside.  How do I wire the two motion sensors so either will trigger the lights to come on?

Answer (score 4):

Wire nut together the motion sensors so that they are in parallel and will then so provide a path to the light if either is switched on.

Here is a wiring diagram (minus the grounds that must be pulled along):

[image: Wiring diagram]

Blacks are hot, red are travelers, and the gray are your neutrals.

Answer (score 1):

They will have to be wired in parallel so either switch can turn on the lights.

The lights will stay on as long as the switch with the longest delay if they are both triggered.

A layout diagram would be helpful to determine how to wire it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and feels more like a comment.

Comment: The first sentence is the technical answer to the OPs question. The rest is advisory.